# Generating multilevel list in Word using interop C#

Tags: c#, ms-word

What I want:

> 1. Heading 1
>
> > 1.1. Heading 2
> >
> > > ```
> > >    1.1.1. Heading 3
> > > ```
> >
> > 1.2. Heading 2
> >
> > Heading 1

and so on.

I see that there exists a list style that accomplishes this, but I can't figure out how to code it.

```
Word.Range rng = wordDoc.Paragraphs.Add().Range;
rng.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplate(...);
```

I'm not sure how to fill the arguments of ApplyListTemplate(), or if that's even the correct approach. I can't find any actual examples of any ListTemplate object, only references to them.

Reference here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.listformat.applylisttemplate(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: but a little bit the title is not so appropriate !! it took me long time to catch it...I would suggest title modification and make more clear and searchable as "Generating multilevel list in Word C#" or " ...~ using interop C#"

Answer (score 1):

I just finished doing this in a document-level add-in. It will be slightly different if yours is an application-level add-in.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = Globals.ThisDocument.Application;
ListGallery gallery = app.ListGalleries[WdListGalleryType.wdOutlineNumberGallery];
// this one matches the numbering in your example, but not the indentation
ListTemplate myPreferredListTemplate = gallery.ListTemplates[5];

Style style = Globals.ThisDocument.Styles["Heading 1"];
style.LinkToListTemplate(myPreferredListTemplate, 1);
```

The galleries appear to be predefined app-level list styles, but you can also create and reuse doc-level `ListTemplate`s through `Document.ListTemplates`.

Creating your own would be how you could get the indentation you need. You'd just have to play around with the settings in the `ListTemplate.ListLevels`.